# Angular2 Http Request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-http

Hi I am trying to make a get request using the `HTTP` module in `Angular2`.

Everything compiles fine in `Typescript` (1.5), but `Chrome` shows the following error the in console:

```
EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of EntryList!. ORIGINAL
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'merge' of undefined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE: TypeError: Cannot read property 'merge' of undefined
at mergeOptions (angular2.dev.js:27991)  
at execute.Http.get (angular2.dev.js:28052)  
at EntryService.getEntries (services.js:17)
at new EntryList (entry-list.js:20)
```

### Services.ts

```typescript
/// <reference path="../typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
import { Http, Observable } from "angular2/angular2"

export class EntryService {
    private _entries: Array<string>;
    private _http : Http;

    constructor() {     
        this._entries = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
        this._http = new Http;      
    }

    get Entries() : Array<string> {
        return this._entries;
    }

    getEntries()
    {
        console.log(this._http);
        return this._http.get('http://localhost:53338/api/decisions')       
            .toRx()
            .map((response) => { 
                response.json()
            });     
    }
}
```

### entry-list.ts

```typescript
/// <reference path="../typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../modules/services.ts" />

import { Component, View, NgFor } from "angular2/angular2"
import { EntryService } from "modules/services"

@Component({
    selector: 'entry-list'  
})
@View({
    directives: [ NgFor ],
    templateUrl: "../views/entry-list.html" 
})
export class EntryList {
    entries: Array<string>; 

    constructor(public service: EntryService) {     
        this.entries = this.service.Entries;
        this.service.getEntries().subscribe((response) => {     
            console.log(response);
        }); 
    }
}
```

### app.ts

```typescript
/// <reference path="typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="components/entry-list.ts" />
/// <reference path="modules/services.ts" />

import { Component, View, bootstrap, NgFor } from "angular2/angular2"
import { EntryList } from "components/entry-list"
import { EntryService } from "modules/services"

@Component({
    selector : "app",
    bindings: [ EntryService ]  
})
@View({
    directives: [ EntryList ],
    templateUrl: "views/app.html"   
})
class App { 
    constructor() {
        console.log('hit');
    }
}

bootstrap(App);
```

### index.html

```typescript
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SCM</title>
        <script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.88/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
        <script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>      
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.34/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <app></app>
        <script>System.import('app')</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I did look at the API documentation on the `angular.io` site, but can't see whats wrong.

## UPDATE

### Services.ts

```typescript
/// <reference path="../typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
import { Http, Observable, httpInjectables } from "angular2/angular2"

export class EntryService {
    private _entries: Array<string>;    

    constructor(private http: Http) {       
        this._entries = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];            
    }

    get Entries() : Array<string> {
        return this._entries;
    }

    getEntries()
    {
        console.log(this.http);
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:53338/api/decisions')        
            .toRx()
            .map((response) => { 
                response.json()
            });     
    }
}
```

### entry-list.ts

```typescript
/// <reference path="../typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../modules/services.ts" />

import { Component, View, NgFor, Http, httpInjectables } from "angular2/angular2"
import { EntryService } from "modules/services"

@Component({
    selector: 'entry-list',
    bindings : [ Http, httpInjectables ]
})
@View({
    directives: [ NgFor ],
    templateUrl: "../views/entry-list.html" 
})
export class EntryList {
    entries: Array<string>; 

    constructor(public service: EntryService) {     
        this.entries = this.service.Entries;
        this.service.getEntries().subscribe((response) => {     
            console.log(response);
        }); 
    }
}
```

### app.ts

```typescript
/// <reference path="typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="components/entry-list.ts" />
/// <reference path="modules/services.ts" />

import { Component, View, bootstrap, NgFor, Http, httpInjectables } from "angular2/angular2"
import { EntryList } from "components/entry-list"
import { EntryService } from "modules/services"

@Component({
    selector : "app",
    bindings: [ EntryService, Http, httpInjectables ]   
})
@View({
    directives: [ EntryList ],
    templateUrl: "views/app.html"   
})
class App { 
    constructor() {
        console.log('hit');
    }
}

bootstrap(App);
```

Without any changes into `index.html`

**Edit: My services.ts file changes to get this working:**

```typescript
/// <reference path="../typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
import { Injector, Http, httpInjectables } from "angular2/angular2"

export class EntryService {
    private _entries: Array<string>;    
    private http: Http;

    constructor() {     
        this._entries = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];        

        var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
                httpInjectables,
                Http
            ]);
        this.http = injector.get(Http);                 
    }

    get Entries() : Array<string> {
        return this._entries;
    }

    getEntries()
    {       
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:53338/api/decisions')        
            .toRx()
            .map(response => response.json());      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should not instantiate Http yourself, instead get it injected :

```
public constructor(http : Http) {
    this.http = http;
}
```

The documentation says :

> Http is available as an injectable class, with methods to perform http requests.

Therefore I am not sure what is the result if you instantiate it yourself, but somehow it can't manage to do the get request due to some internals that are undefined.

Edit: Adding more sources.

```
@Injectable()
export class Http {
    constructor(protected _backend: ConnectionBackend, protected _defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {}

    /**
     * Performs a request with `get` http method.
     */
    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): EventEmitter {
        return httpRequest(this._backend, new Request(mergeOptions(this._defaultOptions, options, RequestMethods.GET, url)));
  }
}
```

Here I added a little part of the Http class from the github repo. You can see that _backend and _defaultOptions are given in the constructor which you don't give, and the method get() will build options for the request based on the options parameter and the _defaultOptions given in the constructor, since you provide none of these, I believe it crashes in the mergeOptions call that you can find here :

```
function mergeOptions(defaultOpts, providedOpts, method, url): RequestOptions {
  var newOptions = defaultOpts;
  if (isPresent(providedOpts)) {
    // Hack so Dart can used named parameters
    newOptions = newOptions.merge(new RequestOptions({
      method: providedOpts.method,
      url: providedOpts.url,
      search: providedOpts.search,
      headers: providedOpts.headers,
      body: providedOpts.body,
      mode: providedOpts.mode,
      credentials: providedOpts.credentials,
      cache: providedOpts.cache
    }));
  }
  if (isPresent(method)) {
    return newOptions.merge(new RequestOptions({method: method, url: url}));
  } else {
    return newOptions.merge(new RequestOptions({url: url}));
  }
}
```

At the last if/else of the function. For more information the source file is located [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/da4bcd5d910478ebcb1a4c3518b5d019ca119fd4/modules/http/src/http.ts).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. First thing I want to try is to inject the Http class down in my EntryService class. As you can see from the code above that there are 3 separate files, I know using the bindings property in the Component annotation will make that object available for injection through out the app, I have tried specifying the Http class there for injection but I get errors on my EntryService constructor if I try to inject that. Do you know how to make the Http object inject-able for the EntryService?

Comment: Actually I just changed the code. And there are no errors, not for the typescript compiler and neither inside chrome, but the app doesn't work.

Comment: you can import httpInjectables from angular2 and pass it directly to your bootstrap call, that's the method I have used myself with success and what seems to be the classic way at the moment. Can you update your code to reflect the latest changes ?

Comment: I have updated the code, I have also tried to pass the Http object into the bootstrap call with no success (Although not in the code above).

Comment: Just give the httpInjectables in the bootstrap, and include only Http in your service. And then you don't need to bind it to your app injector anymore. Could you otherwise try to set a plnkr up and reproduce the issue ?

Comment: Hi sorry for taking so long to respond, I took some time reading the Http.ts files and what ever resources I could find to understand more, and I finally understood your answer better. I still don't know how to inject variables to child classes of child components, but what I did manage to do in my services.ts file is to instanciate an injector and then do a var http = injector.get(Http) and that worked. Code was as follows var injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate([
    httpInjectables,
    Http
   ]);
  this.http = injector.get(Http); Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @Amaud Can you show an example of how to do it in the bootstrap?

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want to use another library just for CRUD/HTTP requests? **

> I would highly recommend es6 de-facto fetch then. It not only is
>   simpler in my opinion as of now than angular2/http, but also the
>   standard now and in future versions.

** It's working out of the box for safari, chrome, ie-edge, and firefox too.

Comment: An example would be helpful to support your case